# How to make elements get position from their transformed forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make something with `transform: scale(0.5, 0.5)` but after I apply this rule, all elements became smaller but their positions remain the same - how can I apply transform to margin, border and padding too?

Comment: Use transform: translate(50px,100px);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `transform-origin: 0 0` but even that isn't enough for your requirement. I can suggest transforming the parent of those elements, if that's an option for you.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/en2xsyqr/), and code below for reference:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="transformed">
  </div>
  <div class="transformed">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.transformed {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  /* transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); */
  /* transform-origin: 0 0; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`transform: scale();` doesn't actually change elements' size in the DOM. Instead, it puts that element on a separate layer, alters its size on the GPU side, then uses this layer to display your element, at the same time preserving your elements' original position and dimensions. If you inspect that element you'll see that its bounding box (outlined in blue) differs from what is actually on your screen.

If you want your elements to affect other elements you'd have to change their actual dimension properties like `width`, `height`, `padding`, etc.
Please note that this seriously affects your page performance if it's used in an animation for example, as these properties trigger complete layout recalculation.

Quick demonstration that transformed elements don't change your layout:

```css
.box
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 10px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.recalc .box
{
  animation: recalc 1s infinite alternate linear;
}

.transform .box
{
  animation: scale 1s infinite alternate linear;
}

.container
{
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px blue;
}

@keyframes scale{
  0%{
  transform: scale(.5, .5);
  },
  100%{
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes recalc{
  0%{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  },
  100%{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-width: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container transform">
  <div class="box">
    Transform
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container recalc">
  <div class="box">
    Prop changes
  </div>
</div>
```